# How do i make a shopping catalog?

Tags: html, css

i've tried to make a shopping catalog. I have made 2 items at the moment and i want them to go side by side and not go from the top to the bottom. I have a picture to show what i mean. https://gyazo.com/c429b34c9e5fdd61ce0922d0eeaabc66
Hope you can help!

```css
<style>
.Button {
    background-color: Plum;
    border: 1px solid;
 border-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
 font-family: hacked;
 border-radius: 8px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
 
}

  .sub {
  position: relative;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}

  
  
  .itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 100%;
 color: Plum;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px Black;
}
body {  
    background-image: url("lightning.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
p  {
   font-size: 150%;
   color: Plum;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px Black;
}
h2 {
  color: DarkGreen;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px Black;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<font size=10><center><h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;text-align: center;">Buy now</h1>
<body background="background.jpg">
<title>Our Future</title>
  <div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">

  <div class="sub">
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="selve_websiten.html">Frontpage</a></button>
    <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="side2.html">About us</a></button>
    </div>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
 
 
 
 
<p style="font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">No Turning Back - Steam Code</p><h2 style="font-size: 34px;font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center;">0,99€</h2>

<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="EmalGod@hotmail.com">

  <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

  <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="No Turning Back - Steam Code">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.99">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_buynow_107x26.png"
  alt="Buy Now">
  <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
</div>

<br></br>

<p style="font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">Tap Adventure: Time Travel Three Rings DLC - Steam Code</p><h2 style="font-size: 34px;font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center;">0,99€</h2>

<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="EmalGod@hotmail.com">

  <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

  <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="No Turning Back - Steam Code">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.99">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_buynow_107x26.png"
  alt="Buy Now">
  <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
</div>
  
  
  
  

</form></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <html><head>
</head>
<body background="background.jpg"><font size="10"><center><h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;text-align: center;">Buy now</h1>

<title>Our Future</title>
  <div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">

  <div class="sub">
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="selve_websiten.html">Frontpage</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="side2.html">About us</a></button>
    </div>
 <br><br>
 <br><br>
 
 
 
 <div class="itemsHolder" style="display: inline-flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div class="item">
<p style="font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">No Turning Back - Steam Code</p><h2 style="font-size: 34px;font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center;">0,99â‚¬</h2>

<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input name="business" value="EmalGod@hotmail.com" type="hidden">

  <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
  <input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">

  <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
  <input name="item_name" value="No Turning Back - Steam Code" type="hidden">
  <input name="amount" value="0.99" type="hidden">
  <input name="currency_code" value="EUR" type="hidden">

  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_buynow_107x26.png" alt="Buy Now" border="0" type="image">
  <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" height="1" border="0" width="1">

</form>
</div>
  </div>

<br><br>
<div class="item">
<p style="font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">Tap Adventure: Time Travel Three Rings DLC - Steam Code</p><h2 style="font-size: 34px;font-family:kenyan coffee;text-align: center;">0,99â‚¬</h2>

<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input name="business" value="EmalGod@hotmail.com" type="hidden">

  <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
  <input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">

  <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
  <input name="item_name" value="No Turning Back - Steam Code" type="hidden">
  <input name="amount" value="0.99" type="hidden">
  <input name="currency_code" value="EUR" type="hidden">

  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_buynow_107x26.png" alt="Buy Now" border="0" type="image">
  <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" height="1" border="0" width="1">

</form>
</div>
  </div>
  
  
  </div>

</div></div></center>



</font></body></html>
```

I englobed the items with one div under a class `itemsHolder` and each item is in a div with a class `item`.

The itemHolder has a `display: inline-flex` to make them look side by side and `flex-wrap: wrap` to place them in a sort of grid.

If you need more space between the items use the class `Item` and add a padding or some margins up to you.

## UPDATE for "how to add a padding"

Since now your items are under a class you can select that class with css and simply add padding to it:

```
.item{
    padding: 20px;
}
```

This will make a padding inside the element of class item of 20px from each side (left, right, top, bottom).

Comment: Thank you, how do you add a margin or padding correctly. Sorry im pretty new to this

Comment: @EmalGodZ Check the updated answer :) Don't forget to check it as an answer if that helped you.

Comment: Hello again, i did as you talk me and made the padding but nothing changed?

Comment: @EmalGodZ Did you replaced your html with the html i provided you?

Comment: Yes, i did do that while still keeping css

Comment: @EmalGodZ then just add that code for padding in your css and it should work.

Comment: I did do that. thats why im confused

Comment: @EmalGodZ Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Like a forgotten } or a non closed dom element.

Comment: @EmalGodZ it's ".item" not "item", you forgot a .

Comment: Why does it do that?

Comment: @EmalGodZ Why it does what? You are not setting the css properly. The slector should have a . for a class. So since you want to apply css to a class you put a . and then item. you wrote item without the . so it thought it has to apply the css to an element of type item.